# Dokka source links not created

Tags: kotlin-dokka

I'm beginning development on a new library and I want to start the project right with the project setup to generate API documentation using dokka.

I'm using gradle as a build tool and I've added the following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    ext.dokka_version = '0.9.15'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:${dokka_version}"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

...

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'

    includes = ['Module.md']

    linkMapping {
        dir = "src/main/kotlin"
        url = "https://<internal bitbucket repo project url>/src/main/kotlin"
        suffix = "#L"
    }
}
```

When I run `gradlew dokka` the documentation gets created correctly, including the module and package documentation I have in the `Modules.md` file. I do not, however, see source links to the bitbucket repo. Would someone please advise how I can get more information from dokka about why such links were not created?

Answer (score 0):

`sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}`

Do this in build.gradle of your app